# Django Celery Beat not sending tasks to Celery Worker

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, django-celery-beat

I am using Celery in Django in order to run tasks in specific time intervals. When I first start the Docker, all the tasks run without any issue. If I stop the docker (i.e. docker-compose down) and then restart the docker (i.e. docker-compose up), celery-beat does not send the tasks to the celery worker in order for them to get executed.

If I visit the Admin panel and disable the tasks and then re-enable them it starts working!

Also if I do not use the django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler and allow celery beat to use the default scheduler it also works. Even though this method works, is not the best scenario since the tasks are not longer editable in Django admin panel

Is there a solution to this issue?

Postgresql is not part of the docker-compose. I have a native PostgreSQL 10.5 installation.

settings.py

```
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "redis://redis:6379",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
            "CONNECTION_POOL_KWARGS":{"max_connections":50, "retry_on_timeout": True}
        }
    }
}

SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache"
SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS = "default"
CELERY_TIMEZONE = "Europe/Amsterdam"
CELERY_TASK_TRACK_STARTED = True
CELERY_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 30 * 60
CELERY_BROKER_URL="redis://redis:6379"
CELERY_CACHE_BACKEND = 'default'
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    "sendemails_task":{
        "task":"demoapp.tasks.testing",
        "schedule":crontab(minute='*/2')
    },
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 6379
  web:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: gunicorn Project.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8001 --workers=4 --preload
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
      - ./uploads/:/home/app/web/uploads/
    expose:
      - 8001
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
  celery:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    command: celery -A Project worker -l info
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    depends_on:
      - web
      - redis
  celery-beat:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    command: celery -A Project beat -l debug --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    depends_on:
      - web
      - redis
      - celery
volumes:
  static_volume:
```

tasks.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
from celery import shared_task
from django.core.cache import cache
import time
import traceback


@shared_task
def testing():
    print('test')
```

celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

import os

from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Project.settings')

app = Celery('Project')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

Comment: Same Problem here

Comment: same problem here following this post